# Why are these two haskell functions not equivalent?

Tags: haskell

I've been looking at these functions:

```
import Data.Digits (digits)
numberDivider (a,b) = a / b
numberDivider2 (num,denom) = num / denom
                              where
                                a = head $ digits 10 num
                                b = head . tail $ digits 10 denom
```

We can look at the types of these functions:

```
λ> :t numberDivider2
numberDivider2 :: (Integral a, Fractional a) => (a, a) -> a
λ> :t numberDivider
numberDivider :: Fractional a => (a, a) -> a
```

The `numberDivider` does what you would think it does. `numberDivider2` gives:

```
No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  ...plus 34 others
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

when called with correct arguments (e.g. (48,98)). Now I don't see how making something more specific leads to ambiguity? I feel that I am being stupid in some way. (I also don't see why the function needs to go from `(a,a) -> a` as I would have thought it would be `(a,a) -> b` where a is `Integral` and b is float or something.

I have tried putting in type annotations to force it to use Float for the result.

Can someone point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: can you give the complete code - I think there are some parts missing - for example I see no call to print, and is the `digits` from here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/digits ?

Comment: if it's `digits` from this package than the answer is that this function needs the additional constraint: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/digits-0.2/docs/Data-Digits.html

Comment: to get rid of your problem with `print` you should constraint your to a concrete type: `numberDivider (49,98) :: Float` but it's hard to tell without the complete code we can try

Comment: @CarstenKönig sorry, the print is just from running it in the repl

Comment: and the `digits`? - well bhekilr made the comments into an answer already - is this everything you need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely coming from the definition of `digits`, which I'm guessing takes an `Integrala => a` as one of its arguments.  This then places the additional constraint of `Integral` on the argument to `numberDivider2`.  As it turns out, there is not a type that is an instance of both `Fractional` and `Integral`.  When you input numeric literals, though, it tries to convert from `Num a => a` to `(Integral a, Fractional a) => a`, and in GHCi there are special rules to try to find an instance that also uses `Show` so that you can print it to the screen.  Since no such type exists, you get an error.

Now, the real problem seems to be arising from a misunderstanding of Haskell's number system.  You can't use `/` on all numbers, such as `Int`s, because `/` is not defined for those types.  You can only use `/` on fractional types, hence the `Fractional` typeclass.  If you want to convert `Int`s or `Integer`s to `Float` or `Double` to perform a floating point division, you can use `fromIntegral` to convert them to any `Num` type, <strike>e.g.</strike>

```
a = head $ digits 10 $ fromIntegral num
b = head . tail $ digits 10 $ fromIntegral denom
```

This should remove the `Integral` constraint from the function.

---

After looking at the type of `digits`, I see that this won't work.  Instead, you probably want something like

```
numberDivider2 :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => (a, a) -> b
numberDivider2 (num, denom) = fromIntegral num / fromIntegral denom
    where
        a = head $ digits 10 num
        b = head . tail $ digits 10 denom
```

Note the location of the `fromIntegral`s, they convert each `Integral` value at the point where you want to perform a `Fractional` operation.

Comment: good answer - sadly I have wasted all my upvotes for today already (wanted the "vox populi") - will give you your deserved +1 in 5 hours ;)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I thought it would be an issue with the number types and you explained it perfectly.

Comment: @CarstenKönig Haha, it's all good, I'm here to answer questions and help people learn, not necessarily get the rep.  Don't get me wrong, the rep is a fun game, but I've already hit 20k, I don't get any more privileges and all that's left is to feel bad while comparing myself to Jon Skeet and his approximate reputation of 390278319874928473598791238480.

Comment: ;) ... but beeing the Jon Skeet of Haskell is something isn't it?

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yeah, but [I'm still only 17th for the haskell tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45578/top-100-users-in-a-given-tag), so I guess I can just sit here and compare myself to Don Stewart with 5x the upvotes I do in this tag =P

Answer (score 4):

> Now I don't see how making something more specific leads to ambiguity?

It's ambiguous in both cases, but in case of `numberDivider` the ambiguity can be resolved using Haskell's defaulting rules. In this particular instance those rules basically say that if multiple numeric types are possible and one of them is `Integer`, pick `Integer`. If `Integer` is not possible, but `Double` is, pick `Double`. If neither are possible, the ambiguity remains.

In case of `numberDivider` `Integer` is not possible because `Integer` is not an instance of `Fractional`, but `Double` is. Therefore `Double` is picked.

In case of `numberDivider` neither is possible because there simply is no type that's both `Integral` and `Fractional`. Therefore the ambiguity remains.

You might argue that a set of exactly 0 possible types isn't ambiguous, but simply impossible, so the error message should be different, but it also has to take into account instances that might be defined elsewhere. That is, while there aren't any types that are both `Fractional` and `Integral` in the standard library, they might be defined somewhere else, so we can't exclude that possibility (even though it would make no sense).